# Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string

Tags: java, string, underscore-java

```
public int countCode(String str) {
  int code = 0;
  
  for(int i=0; i<str.length()-3; i++){
    if(str.substring(i, i+2).equals("co") && str.charAt(i+3)=='e'){
      code++;
    }
  }
  return code;
}
```

Hi guys, I've solved this problem by some help among the internet.  But the actual problem that I'm facing is this, `(str.length()-3)` in the for loop.  I don't understand why the `str.length()-3` having this `-3` in it.  please explain it...

Comment: becuase of `str.charAt(i+3)`. If you would not use 3` you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: hi... but, i was asking about the for loop condition str.length()-3. why is that coming, what is the purpose of that -3 there. And how is that -3 is making effect in my code... please explain this...

Comment: It doesn't look like you are counting the occurrences of the word `code`.  It appears you are counting the appearances of the words `co*e`  where `*` is any letter. Please clarify.

Comment: Use `str.regionMatches(i, "co", 0, 2)` instead of `str.substring(i, i+2).equals("co")` to avoid unnecessary allocation.

Comment: Also, you may as well do `i += 3` when you do `code++`, because you know that the next "code" can't start until after the "e".

Comment: The word "code" is 4 letters long.  You only need to check until the last possible position, where the "c" in "code" is 3 letters back from the end,  If the keyword was "language", you'd stop checking 7 positions from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop, for any index (`i`), it checks that the chars at `i` and `i+2` and `i+3` match your requirements. If your `i` becomes length of your string (or last character), then the code will throw exception since it will try to find `char` at position which is not really there.

Comment: hi... but, i was asking about the for loop condition str.length()-3.  why is that coming, what is the purpose of that -3 there.  And how is that -3 is making effect in my code... please explain this...

Comment: The (i-3) makes sure that the loop skips the last 3 chars. For ex. while iterating the string 'deviprasath', the (i-3) will make sure that it does not evaluate for the last 3 chars i.e. 'ath'. Because for these 3 chars, charAt will throw exception as there won't be any char on those indexes. Hope this is a more informative.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of posting an answer which someone might actually use in a production system, we can try a replacement approach:

```java
public int countCode(String str) {
    return (str.length() - str.replace("code", "").length()) / 4;
}
```

Comment: You may want to change `str.replace("code", "")` to `str.replaceAll("co.e", "")` since that is what the OPs code is looking for.  I enquired about this since it wasn't clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assume String is length `10`.  When I goes from `0 to < 10` `i.e. 0 to 9`, the test `str.charAt(i+3)=='e'` will cause `i + 3` to exceed the length of the string when `i >= 7`, and throw an exception.  By limiting `i` to `3 less than the length`, the loop will terminate before the index goes out of bounds.

Regarding your solution, I would offer the following alternative.

- `split("co.e",-1)` will split on the word `co.e` where `.` matches any character. The `-1` will ensure trailing empty strings will be preserved (in case the string ends with `codecodecode`  So the number array size would be `1 + the number of delimiters encountered` so subtracting one is required.

```
public static int countCode(String str) {
        return (int)str.split("co.e",-1).length-1;
}
```

Since `split` takes a regex, either `code` or `co.e` can be used.

**Updated**

Better still would be to use [Andy Turner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) suggestion and increment do `i += 3` when do `code++` count.